# Escolher Certificado através do CNPJ

Tags: c#

Eu tenho esta função que busca o certificado pelo serial:

```
 public static X509Certificate2 EscolherCertificado()
    {
        var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        X509Certificate2 x509 = null;

        var Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "serialcertificadoaqui", false);
        if (fcollection.Count == 1)
        {
            return fcollection[0];
        }
        else { return null; }

    }
```

Porém de início eu não vou saber o serial, como posso buscar o serial do certificado através de uma função ? Sem o usuário precisar digitar, é possível ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, mudando esta linha:

```
X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "serialcertificadoaqui", false);
```

para esta:

```
 X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, doc, false);
```

Em doc eu passo o cnpj somente números, e ele conseguiu encontrar.